# Multiple If conditions in a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

i want to write multiple if conditions to check the values of different columns of a same table in a trigger. i am checking for the two columns right now and i am getting the mysql error

> ```
> #1064(syntax error) at Line # 17.
> ```

following are my conditions. plz help me what im doing wrong.

```
IF (OLD.CE_EN_OPTION_ID != NEW.CE_EN_OPTION_ID)
THEN
INSERT INTO  audit_log(
BENEFICIARY_ID ,
TABLE_NAME ,
FIELD_NAME ,
OLD_VALUE ,
NEW_VALUE ,
EDIT_BY,
DATE_TIME
)
VALUES (
OLD.BENEFICIARY_ID,  'be_ce_main',  'CE_EN_OPTION_ID', OLD.CE_EN_OPTION_ID, NEW.CE_EN_OPTION_ID, NEW.EDITED_ID,NOW()
);
END IF;

IF(OLD.CE_DM_OPTION_ID != NEW.CE_DM_OPTION_ID)
THEN
INSERT INTO  audit_log(
BENEFICIARY_ID ,
TABLE_NAME ,
FIELD_NAME ,
OLD_VALUE ,
NEW_VALUE ,
EDIT_BY,
DATE_TIME
)
VALUES (
OLD.BENEFICIARY_ID,  'be_ce_main',  'CE_DM_OPTION_ID', OLD.CE_DM_OPTION_ID, NEW.CE_DM_OPTION_ID, NEW.EDITED_ID,NOW()
);
END IF;
```

Comment: What is the trigger definition like `create trigger ...`? Post it too.

Comment: And which part of the code is line number `17`

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER 'test_trigger' AFTER UPDATE ON 'be_ce_main' FOR EACH ROW

Comment: @Ravider second IF condition starts at line 17..if i use only 1 if condition then it works accurately

Comment: @echo_Me full erro is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near IF(OLD.CE_DM_OPTION_ID != NEW.CE_DM_OPTION_ID)
THEN
INSERT INTO  audit_log(
B at line # 17

Comment: problem solved i was missing the BEGIN keyword before IF conditions and END keyword after IF conditions..thanks everyone for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `BEGIN` - `END` block. 
And I fear you did not override `delimiter` to instruct sql engine to not execute statements ending with default statement terminator `;` semicolon. Because you didn't define new delimiter, sql engine assumed it was the end of statement at first found `;` semicolon. There it failed because the statements are not in proper syntax order.

Try the following:

```
Delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER 'test_trigger' AFTER UPDATE ON 'be_ce_main' FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN -- this is a must if you have more than one executable statements below

-- your trigger body here

END;
//

Delimiter ;
```

**Refer to**:

[MySQL: Create Trigger Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html)